# Using denavit hartenberg parameters with xacro

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I describe a robot arm using DH parameters and xacro? Is it documented somewhere? I imagine it is pretty straightforward, but I cannot find an exampe.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190579/using-denavit-hartenberg-parameters-with-xacro/) by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2014-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about the mrpt library?
http://www.mrpt.org/list-of-mrpt-apps/application-robotic-arm-kinematics/
I really don t know whether you can use xacro or not, but perhaps it could help you

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0